# What form of output is this from Eigensystem?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been using DSolve and Eigensystem to analyze a 4x4 and some 2x2 system(s) of symbolic 1st-order linear ordinary differential equations. I just tried Eigensystem on a 3x3 matrix and encountered a problem I haven't seen before. The matrix is `{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`. Here's the first eigenvalue from E-system: `Root[c*e*g - b*f*g - c*d*h + a*f*h + b*d*i - a*e*i + (-(b*d) + a*e - c*g - f*h + a*i + e*i)*#1 + (-a - e - i)*#1^2 + #1^3 & ,  1]` I don't know what to make of this. Previously, multiplication was just, e.g., `c e g`, and square roots were rendered as actual square roots, and I never saw anything like `#1^2` or `#1^3`. Can someone explain what this is and how to get standard form output in this case? Thank you.

Comment: '#1' is the first parameter in a pure function, denoted by the ampersand '&' there at the end of that term.

Comment: Have a look at what `Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 1]` and `Root[a #^2 + b # + c &, 2]` evaluate to.

Comment: Use result/.{a->1.0  ,...} to get numerical results. With symbols only as matrix elements, you only get an answer equavalent to the eigenvalue equations det(A-lambda IdentityMatrix[Length[A]])=0. For a diagonal Matrix its an polynomial equation of degree Length[A], that is invariant under linear transformations. Generally such equations have no algebraic finite forms, only for small dimensions 1..4 they can be abtractly given by definite root expressions. For n>=5 one simply uses the expression=0, kth root,  as a symbol.